# Does the American Health Care Act include a defined list of preexisting conditions?

Tags: united-states, healthcare

I have seen many people denouncing the AHCA because it defines certain things as preexisting conditions, such as rape, abuse, or mental health treatment. Does the AHCA contain *any* list of preexisting conditions? Or does it simply allow states and/or insurance companies to make their own list?

Answer (score 5):

The same question was asked at [skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/38202/is-sexual-assualt-considered-a-pre-existing-condition-in-the-new-us-health-care).

To summarize: The AHCA allows states to opt-out of some ACA regulations regarding pre-existing conditions; specifically, insurers may increase costs based on pre-existing conditions.

The AHCA itself does not contain a list of approved or protected pre-existing conditions. Insurers have in the past rated issues related to rape or abuse as pre-existing condition, and the AHCA would allow them to do so again in the future.